# NotSupportedException when generating Azure API App Client from swagger file

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-api-apps, swashbuckle

I've got a swagger metadata file generated by Swashbuckle from my Web Api service. When I try generating Azure API App Client (using Visual Studio 2015 > Add > Azure API App Client > Swagger metadata file, the following error is thrown:

```
Generating client code and adding to project started
Generate client code for Microsoft Azure API App with following parameters:
Microsoft Azure API App Name: Contoso.Api1, Base namespace: Automation.Http, Metadata file path: C:\Users\contoso\Desktop\swagger_current.json
[Info]AutoRest Core 0.9.7.0
[Info]Initializing code generator.
[Info]Successfully initialized CSharp Code Generator 1.0.5584.22489
[Info]Initializing modeler.
[Info]Successfully initialized Swagger Modeler 1.0.5584.22490
[Info]Parsing swagger json file.
[Info]Generating client model from swagger model.
[Info]Initializing code generator.
[Info]Successfully initialized CSharp Code Generator 1.0.5584.22489
[Fatal]Error generating syntax tree: Failure during generation of method PutItem.
Failure during serialization generation of method PutItem.
System.NotSupportedException: Contoso.Api.Types.ContosoModel - False

System.NotSupportedException: Contoso.Api.Types.ContosoModel - False
   at Hyak.SerializationGenerator.CreateSerializationMethod(ISerializationBase serializationFormat)
   at Hyak.JsonSerializationGenerator.SerializeJsonRequest[T](StatementsBuilder`1 builder, IJsonBase root)
   at Hyak.JsonSerializationFramework.Serialize[T](ISerializationBase serialization, StatementsBuilder`1& builder)
   at Hyak.CodeGeneratorExtensions.SerializationExtensions`1.Serialize(IDictionary`2 requestBodyDefinitions, Type& requestType)
   at Hyak.ClientGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass3a`1.<SerializeRequest>b__37()
   at Hyak.Ensure.ErrorContext(Action action, String context)
Exception: There was an error during code generation when trying to add a client for the Microsoft Azure API App
Generating client code and adding to project failed
Adding client for Microsoft Azure API App failed
```

I guess I use in my model something which isn't supported by the generator.
Can I somehow get more detailed error message explaining what's wrong?

Comment: I assume that you've checked that your Swagger works in http://editor.swagger.io/?

Comment: Another option is to use [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) (free and open source) to generate the C# API client (or server stub in ASP.net) with your swagger specification.

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question? I am running into the same issue. The editor.swagger.io is not giving me any errors back.

Comment: We are having the same issue here and editor.swagger.io does not show any errors, just some warnings. But it seems it is extremely fragile...

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, I had used/enabled "*c.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds*" in **SwaggerConfig.cs** , this caused problems: **Error generating syntax tree** + **failure during generation of method** + **failure during serialization generation of method** + **System.NotSupportedException** The consequence of this was that the definition "items": { "$ref":" in .json was generated incorrect.